# How to Ant proxy Windows Environmental Variables

Tags: ant, proxy, ivy

I am trying to get ANT and IVY to work behind proxy server.

SetProxy task works OK

```
<target name="proxy">
    <property name="proxy.host" value="proxy.server.com" />
    <property name="proxy.port" value="8080" />
    <setproxy proxyhost="${proxy.host}" proxyport="${proxy.port}" />
</target>
```

But when I tried to use Environmental Variables

```
set ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"
```

Ivy cannot connect to repos and here is the Ant properties output for proxy

```
[echoproperties] http.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort\=8080
```

When I tried "autoproxy" argument to no avail

```
ant -autoproxy deploy
```

Here is the out of ANT

```
C:\Workspace\DevProjects\fxin>ant -Dproxy.host=proxy.eur.xerox.com -Dproxy.port=8000 deploy
Buildfile: C:\Workspace\DevProjects\fxin\build.xml

load-properties:
     [echo] Using properties file: build.properties

download-ivy:
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Wed Dec 14 10:05:03 GMT 2011
[echoproperties] ant.core.lib=C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant.jar
[echoproperties] ant.file=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\build.xml
[echoproperties] ant.file.fxin=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\build.xml
[echoproperties] ant.file.type=file
[echoproperties] ant.file.type.fxin=file
[echoproperties] ant.home=C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2
[echoproperties] ant.java.version=1.7
[echoproperties] ant.library.dir=C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib
[echoproperties] ant.project.default-target=usage
[echoproperties] ant.project.invoked-targets=deploy
[echoproperties] ant.project.name=fxin
[echoproperties] ant.version=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
[echoproperties] app.copyright=2011-2012
[echoproperties] app.name=fxin
[echoproperties] app.vendor=MyUser
[echoproperties] app.version=0.1
[echoproperties] appserver.home=C\:\\Users\\MyUser/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.22
[echoproperties] appserver.lib=C\:\\Users\\MyUser/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/lib
[echoproperties] awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
[echoproperties] basedir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin
[echoproperties] build.dir=war/WEB-INF/classes
[echoproperties] build.properties=build.properties
[echoproperties] db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[echoproperties] db.pw=demo
[echoproperties] db.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/demo
[echoproperties] db.user=demo
[echoproperties] deploy.path=C\:\\Users\\MyUser/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps
[echoproperties] file.encoding=Cp1252
[echoproperties] file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
[echoproperties] file.separator=\\
[echoproperties] ivy.install.version=2.2.0-rc1
[echoproperties] ivy.jar.file=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib\\tools\\ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar
[echoproperties] ivy.retrieve.pattern=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib/[conf]/[organisation]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]
[echoproperties] ivy.settings.file=${res.ivy.dir}/ivysettings.xml
[echoproperties] java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
[echoproperties] java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
[echoproperties] java.class.path=C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-launcher.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-antlr.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-oro.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-commons-logging.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-commons-net.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-jai.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-javamail.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-jdepend.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-jmf.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-jsch.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-junit.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-junit4.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-launcher.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-netrexx.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-swing.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant-testutil.jar;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\lib\\ant.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\lib\\tools.jar
[echoproperties] java.class.version=51.0
[echoproperties] java.endorsed.dirs=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
[echoproperties] java.ext.dirs=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\ext;C\:\\Windows\\Sun\\Java\\lib\\ext
[echoproperties] java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre
[echoproperties] java.io.tmpdir=C\:\\TEMP\\
[echoproperties] java.library.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin;C\:\\Windows\\Sun\\Java\\bin;C\:\\Windows\\system32;C\:\\Windows;C\:\\Program Files\\App\\App Feature Islands\\;C\:\\Windows\\system32;C\:\\Windows;C\:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C\:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C\:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\instantclient_10_2;C\:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Roxio Shared\\DLLShared\\;C\:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Roxio Shared\\10.0\\DLLShared\\;C\:\\Tools\\cygwin\\bin;C\:\\Tools\\bin;C\:\\Program Files\\7-Zip;C\:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin;C\:\\Tools\\apache-ant-1.8.2\\bin;C\:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin;C\:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin;.
[echoproperties] java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
[echoproperties] java.runtime.version=1.7.0-b147
[echoproperties] java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
[echoproperties] java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[echoproperties] java.specification.version=1.7
[echoproperties] java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[echoproperties] java.vendor.url=http\://java.oracle.com/
[echoproperties] java.vendor.url.bug=http\://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
[echoproperties] java.version=1.7.0
[echoproperties] java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
[echoproperties] java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.version=1.7
[echoproperties] java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[echoproperties] java.vm.version=21.0-b17
[echoproperties] lib.build.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib\\compile
[echoproperties] lib.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib
[echoproperties] lib.runtime.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib\\runtime
[echoproperties] lib.test.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib\\test
[echoproperties] lib.tools.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\lib\\tools
[echoproperties] line.separator=\r\n
[echoproperties] os.arch=x86
[echoproperties] os.name=Windows 7
[echoproperties] os.version=6.1
[echoproperties] path.separator=;
[echoproperties] proxy.host=proxy.server.com
[echoproperties] proxy.port=8000
[echoproperties] report.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\report
[echoproperties] report.ivy.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\report\\ivy
[echoproperties] report.javac.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin\\report\\javac
[echoproperties] res.dir=res
[echoproperties] res.ivy.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin
[echoproperties] source.encoding=UTF-8
[echoproperties] source.version=1.5
[echoproperties] src.dir=src
[echoproperties] sun.arch.data.model=32
[echoproperties] sun.boot.class.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\resources.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\rt.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\sunrsasign.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\jsse.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\jce.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\charsets.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\classes
[echoproperties] sun.boot.library.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\bin
[echoproperties] sun.cpu.endian=little
[echoproperties] sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
[echoproperties] sun.desktop=windows
[echoproperties] sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
[echoproperties] sun.java.command=org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -Dproxy.host proxy.server.com -Dproxy.port 8000 deploy
[echoproperties] sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
[echoproperties] sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
[echoproperties] sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
[echoproperties] sun.os.patch.level=
[echoproperties] test.dir=test
[echoproperties] tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
[echoproperties] tomcat.manager.url=http\://localhost\:8080/manager
[echoproperties] tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
[echoproperties] user.country=US
[echoproperties] user.country.format=GB
[echoproperties] user.dir=C\:\\Workspace\\DevProjects\\fxin
[echoproperties] user.home=C\:\\Users\\MyUser
[echoproperties] user.language=en
[echoproperties] user.name=MyUser
[echoproperties] user.script=
[echoproperties] user.timezone=
[echoproperties] user.variant=
[echoproperties] web.dir=war
[echoproperties] web.lib=war/WEB-INF/lib
     [echo] installing ivy...
      [get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0-rc1/ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar
      [get] To: C:\Workspace\DevProjects\fxin\lib\tools\ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar
      [get] Error getting http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0-rc1/ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar to C:\Workspace\DevProjects\fxin\lib\tools\ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have finally got it to work by setting the Env. variable without the surrounding double qoutes

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.eur.xerox.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8000
```

For some reason with double quotes or specifying on the command didn't work.  Proxy setting had to be in environmental variable with quotes.

To add further;

according to http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#proxy

specifying proxy settings on command wouldn't work, as they would be standard ANT properties not JVM options

Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks. I have to provide username and password also, and thought it just wasn't going to work from the command line.  But it was the surrounding double-quotes that caught me too.
set ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.mywork.co.nz -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=domain\myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password123

Comment: Did you run your set command on command line, or did you place it in your ivysettings.xml?

Comment: Thanks, surrounding quotes caught me to. The documentation shows it with the quotes, which is why we all got caught.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting wrong properties.

Try

```
-Dproxy.host=proxy.server.com -Dproxy.port=8080
```

Comment: I had tried that as well but still doesn't work.  In echoproperties list proxy.host property shows but proxy.port is shown as if it was a Java argument with escaped equals sign.

Comment: @rojanu.  Please post your `<echoproperties>` command.  Also, do no set ANT_OPTS, but pass these properties on the `ant` command line